# Input radio checked по умолчанию не переключается через label

Tags: html, html5, input, label, radio

Суть простая, есть `(n)` количество radio-кнопок из которой одна должна быть выбрана по умолчанию.

Есть одно правило label должен идти после input'a для связки в css input:checked+label

Но так почему-то не работает переключение между ними

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="1" checked>
  <label for="1">Кнопка 1</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="2">
  <label for="2">Кнопка 2</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="3">
  <label for="3">Кнопка 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно, чтобы выбирался только один радио инпут, у них должен быть одинаковый `name`:

```html
<div>
  <input name="radio" type="radio" id="1" checked>
  <label for="1">Кнопка 1</label>
  <br>
  <input name="radio" type="radio" id="2">
  <label for="2">Кнопка 2</label>
  <br>
  <input name="radio" type="radio" id="3">
  <label for="3">Кнопка 3</label>
</div>
```

ps Если физически не нажимается, то приложите css без него невозможно угадать что там.